# How to implement Dropbox OAuth in command line Java?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, dropbox

I am trying to create a purely command line based dropbox client for myself. How do I get the authorization code for the token without opening the browser. How do I use the Google OAuth API for Java to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox doesn't offer a way to get an access token without using the browser. The user (in this case, you) needs to go to Dropbox to authorize the app, but this only needs to be done once.

I recommend using the Dropbox Java Core SDK:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/java

The tutorial here shows you how to do this with a command line app:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java

Or, even simpler, since this is only for your own account, you can generate an access token for your account for an app you own using the "Generate" access token button on the app's page on the App Console:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps

Comment: So basically, there is no way to get a token without opening the browser and manually copying the key?

Comment: Correct, one way or another, you'll need to be in the browser once in order to get an access token. Again though, you just need to do that once. With that access token, your app can make API calls without further manual user intervention/browser use.